# PHPStorm + XDebug Setup Walkthrough

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

Up until recently, I've been writing code in PHP (via Notepad++) and debugging by checking the logs in IIS (gotta love that web-platform installer); I've since decided to update to a more efficient code-writing / testing environment, and after playing around for several moments with PHPStorm, decided to purchase it and give it a try. Since then, I have realized that in so far as tutorials and walk-throughs are concerned, PHPStorm is coming up a little short. Having given the manual a glance (RTFM, I know), and come up wanting, I'd like to ask if anyone out there would like to hand hold me through setting up PHPStorm with  XDebug so I can stop hating myself for not studying the underlying systems well enough, and get back to coding.

TLDR; Could someone post a detailed walk-through for setting up PHPStorm + XDebug? Assume maximum level of stupidity on my part (I"m usually more than capable in the ASP.NET world, but I am approaching the intelligence level usually associated with some forms of sea-faring sponge in the PHP world).

The environment is Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit) with IIS & PHP installed.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but there are a number of XDebug helpers available for all major browsers which make it easy to connect to your debug session. Check out https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc for Chrome.

Comment: You went from Notepad to PHPStorm :) :) lol

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's really simple to get Xdebug working with PhpStorm, just [follow this guide carefully](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/). (**NOTE:** [Updated version of the guide is here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm))

For more advanced topics [read this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0/).

Comment: Should I download the TS or non-TS version of XDebug? The automatic instructions generator can't parse anything useful from the "php -i" info I gave it.

Comment: That would depend on the PHP version that you have, check the output of phpinfo() on a dummy page or try to figure it out from the `php -i` yourself.

Comment: Hmm. The threaded version appears to be most appropriate, but the install instructions are lacking...

Comment: If the automatic instructions generate can't parse it, file a bug report? (http://bugs.xdebug.org)

Comment: Bah, my bad on the php -i. Tried to pipe everything to an existing file, got the wrong contents. Got the right info via the IIS console, which generated more proper instructions (it doesn't like the Program Files directory, shortening it to Program, but that happens...).

Comment: There is a newer version of the guide here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Answer (score 40):

I've found a more modern and easier solution partially based on CrasyCoder's post.
The steps you need to do are the following:

1. If your brand new php installation doesn't contain php.ini, rename the php.ini-development to php.ini
2. Install xdebug with help of the wizard: http://xdebug.org/wizard.php Follow its recommendations literally.
3. Put in your php.ini the string: xdebug.remote_enable=1
4. Go to PhpStorm's settings: settings->php. Select or reselect directory containing php. Make sure you see 'Debugger: Xdebug x.x.x' string (where x.x.x stands for installed version)
5. Install an extension for your favorite browser from here: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote
6. From the main menu (not the settings window) go to 'Run->Edit configurations' and add new 'PHP Built-in Web Server' configuration. Point the 'Document root' to your project's directory. Note the port number.
7. Chrome browser: enable the extension pressing on the little bug in the rightmost side of the omnibox and selecting the Debug option. Other browsers' extensions should work similarly.
8. In PhpStorm's menu enable the 'Run -> Start Listen for PHP Debug connections' option.
9. Set a breakpoint in your code in PhpStorm.
10. Run (not debug) the configuration you created in step 6.
11. In your browser go to localhost:port where 'port' is the port from step 6. Your PhpStorm should stop on the breakpoint and you can start squashing bugs in your code.

Considering that:

Steps `1-5` are made once per php installation.
Step  `6` is made once per PhpStorm project.
Steps `7-8` are made once per debuggin session.
Steps `9-11` are made each program run.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you. But: "Error: Built-in web server is only available since PHP 5.4" Mine is 5.3.8 ...

Comment: Please do not assume everyone is using PHP's Built-in webserver. Instructions are needed for using this with an existing/configured Nginx and FPM configuration.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, after countless hours. Jetbrains software have generally been great for me, but getting PHPStorm to  debug has been very frustrating.

Comment: I had it finally working after clicking on the browser icons on the top right of the editor view. They only are visible when hovering on them

Answer (score 11):

**1. install xdebug module**   *(MAC installation steps)*
1.1.1. check what PHP version u r using    `php --ini`   (see the loaded file)
1.1.2. `brew search xdebug`
1.1.3. brew install `phpXX-xdebug`
1.1.4. see details:      `php -i | grep xdebug`
1.2. restart server
1.3. configuration
1.3.1. `sudo find /usr -name 'xdebug.so'`
1.3.2. copy the path of the exact one you need
`example:  /usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.3.2/xdebug.so`
1.3.3. edit the extension related configuration file which should be injected to the main php.ini automatically:
`subl /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini`
1.3.4. add the `zend_extension` to be = the path copied above

```
 [xdebug]  
 zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.3.2/xdebug.so"
```

Normal file should have something like this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"


xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

**2. check your PHP version**
`php --ini`
**3. setup the IDE settings**
preference > languages and framework > PHP >
3.1. set the language level to the correct PHP version of this project
3.2. set an interpreter (set the parent directory of where the bin directory of PHP executable is loaded)
   3.2.1. click the … button > click the + button > other local > set PHP Excitable path,
to find the path type in the terminal: `$ which php`
`example: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.5/bin/php`
**4. restart phpstorm**
**5. now let’s make it work**
5.1. run > edit configuration > click the green + button on the left > select b. php web application
5.2. name: anything example ur {application name - debugger}
5.3. server: localhost (browse > + > name: whatever | host: localhost or 127.0.0.1)
5.4. click ok
5.5. start url: the link of ur project homepage: `http://127.0.0.1:80/SomethingNew/`
5.6. click ok
**6. now set the break point and click debug**

Comment: Best walkthrough I've seen on the subject. Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had quite some troubles when I touched XDebug remote debugging the first time yesterday.

A few general hints, you are overflown with various tutorials and guides anyway.

- Your XDebug configuration on PHP/Aache side:
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
  xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
- You need to either use remote_connect_back as given above (be careful, this means other people can debug your server too while it is enabled) or you specify your IP address (remote_host).
- On Client Side you need to have your router forward the Port 9000 !
- You need to allow PHPStorm for incoming connections in your Firewall (was not enabled by default on Windows 8 for me). Either open Port 9000 or the app itself.
- On PHPStorm make sure to go into Debug configuration and not use the default debug (PHPUnit!) Use "PHP remote debug" (Run/Debug Configurations -> The PLUS sign on upper left)
- You will need to tell PHPStorm the absolute path of your project on the webserver, if you make an error here (and forget that) you will get a prompt anyway.
- Now Debug your project in PHPStorm while having "Listen for connections" enabled and put a breakpoint into your code.
- With your webbrowser open your website/php file while having a cookie enabled that starts the debugger. (cookie is the best approach in most cases). You can use a bookmark (google for phpstorm debugging bookmark) or an extension.

Even following the guides, I missed several of the above points. I hope I could save some hours of struggling :)

Comment: Plus one for the xdebug.remote_connect_back=1  part! Thank you

Comment: Be careful with the setting, it's dangerous if you keep it accidentially

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need  remote debug, you can easily debug your project.

First check your php.ini settings.

Be sure that your xdebug dll exists and the settings are on.

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Then go to Run menu in top navbar. Then select edit configurations and add new configuration ( do not change your default settings for another project )

[image: phpStorm add new configuration]
Click add new item button.

After adding new **php web application**

If you do not have any server ( generally points the localhost with 80 port on windows or linux ) click the button shown as below.

[image]

Add a new server with xdebug.

[image]

Then click ok and check your configuration

[image]

Finally, you will see the configuration at the right side of ide.

[image]

Click RUN or DEBUG button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. install xdebug on your local PHP - actually update your php v with xdebug included:
   https://floyk.com/en/post/how-to-update-php-version-on-your-macbook-macos-sierra
2. setup your xdebug.ini

   zend_extension=/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
   [xdebug]
   xdebug.remote_enable=on
   xdebug.default_enable=on
   xdebug.remote_autostart=off
   xdebug.remote_port=9000
   xdebug.remote_host=localhost
   xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
   xdebug.profiler_output_name=xdebug-profile-cachegrind.out-%H-%R
   xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
   xdebug.var_display_max_data = 512
   xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
   xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
   xdebug.file_link_format = phpstorm://open?%f:%l
3. Install Xdebug helper to your Chrome browser:
   [Install Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc)
4. in your PhpStorm go to Settings/Preferences->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Debug

- Update your Automatically detect IDE IP if needed, and press OK

You are done.

More detailed "step by step" guide you can find here:

https://floyk.com/en/post/how-install-php-with-xdebug-on-mac-os