# Configure xdegub on phpstorm for Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework2, phpstorm, xdebug

I have been trying to configure PHPStorm 8.0 with xdebug to debug a project running on zendframework2.

So far, the PHPStorm and xdebug seem to be ok.

After setting a breakpoint on /application/public/index.php and after enabling the debugger on the browser through the bookmarklets, I set the phpstorm to "listen" to incomming debugging connections but so far nothing has been triggered on the phpstorm as it is supposed to happen.

I followed the guides provided on:

[phpstorm-xdebug-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183179/phpstorm-xdebug-setup-walkthrough)

but none of them provide information related to zendframework or any other framework.

Anyone who debugs zf2 projects with phpstorm+xdebug can help me with the right configurations on phpstorm?

Comment: *"but none of them provide information related to zendframework or any other framework."* -- that's because there is no need for that: debugger debugs your PHP files without checking what framework it is (it will be php file anyway). Since I have no idea of what and how you have configured it, what's your setup is etc -- I may only suggest to watch this video as well: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Comment: Thanks! I'll watch it carefully