# How to setup PHPStorm debugger

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I am running Windows 10 (TP) x64.
I have installed latest XAMPP and manually updated PHP to 5.6.7.
I didn't updated phpMyAdmin (Version information: 4.2.11, latest stable version: 4.4.2).
I have downloaded latest Xdebug 2.3.2 extension (VC11, thread-safe, 32-bit), and installed it by copying a file into "C:\xampp\php\ext" folder. I have saved a copy of original xdebug DLL file (just named differently).
I have enabled Xdebug extension by updating "C:\xampp\php\php.ini" file (final section of the INI file):

> [XDebug]
>   zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
>   ;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
>   ;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
>   ;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
>   ;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
>   ;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
>   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
>   ;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
>   xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
>   xdebug.remote_port = 9000
>   xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
>   ;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
>   
>   (how do I exit this block?! -.-'''')
>   I have started Apache and MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel.
>   In PHPStorm, I have created a new/empty PHP project (using PHP interpreter from C:\xampp\php), wrote some code (doing a login system).
>   [image: Settings]
>   And connected PHPStorm MySQL to XAMPP MySQL:
>   [image: XAMPP CP]
>   [image: PHPStorm Database]
>   Everything gone well so far.. Until PHPStorm started to throw errors at me.
>   [image: PHPStorm Server Validation Fails]
>   As I don't know how to setup a debbuger (Xdebug) with PHPStorm.
>   I want to be able to debug localhost / 127.0.0.1 completely.
>   For example, POST/HTTP requests, as I submit a form in web-browser (Google Chrome/Mozilla Firefox/Internet Explorer/Safari/Opera, any, I have them all).
>   I want to step-through everything on my PHP file.
>   I have watched a video on YT (until he skipped entire step over configuring server..) and readed PHPStorm docs, but despite it..
>   Do I need to setup Google Chrome or web-browser, perhaps install extension?
>   And I'm completely lost right now, I'm not even sure if I am in the right direction.
>   Above I said what I want; complete control and debug a session in PHPStorm as I browse my PHP website in Google Chrome or any other web-browser.
>   
>   I am willing to share my TeamViewer credentials. Somebody, just configure this for me - please.
>   
>   Thanks in advance. Greetings from OmegaExtern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for PHPStorm support

Comment: "started to throw errors at me"... so what are those errors?

Comment: @Machavity Please don't close.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not even sure. I don't know what configuration to pick.. "PHP Built-in Web Server", "PHP HTTP Request", "PHP Remote Debug".... Whatever I try to configure, for example, PHP Web Application, when I validate it throws this: github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/issues/404

Comment: @arkascha: See: http://i.imgur.com/hCD1bhO.png

Comment: OK; so if your real question is how to setup the debugger inside PHPStorm, then I partly agree with @Machavity: you should consult the applications documentation (that is what is has been written for!) or their support if you cannot make sense from it.

Comment: [PHPStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html) is quite good. Also, this question [has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183179/phpstorm-xdebug-setup-walkthrough). I think it's off-topic though, and the other question also has a link-only answer to the docs. Those links, and many others, can easily by found by just googling for something like 'PHPStorm setup XDebug' or something.

Comment: Solved my problem. It is pretty simple at the end. What I have had missed was to go to my PHP webpage, assign a cookie called "XDEBUG_SESSION" holding a value of xdebug.idekey set in php.ini file (PHPSTORM). Then, in PHPStorm, "Start listening for PHP Debug Connections". Reload a webpage. And accept the incoming connection in PHPStorm. Thanks for help guys.