# How to set up Xdebug for PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I installed and configured the Xdebug for PhpStorm. When I open phpinfo, I see that IDEkey is same as IDEkey in PhpStorm `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug -> DBGp Proxy`.

**When I start debug session, it open page in browser but script doesn't stop on point, and variables doesn't show in the debug panel.**

This if for PHP 7.2.6, Xdebug version 2.6.1 and PhpStorm 2017.3.6

[image: configure phpstrom1]

[image: phpinfo]

[image: configure PhpStorm]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPStorm + XDebug Setup Walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183179/phpstorm-xdebug-setup-walkthrough)

Comment: iirc you need a browser plugin too?

Comment: Yeah might need this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

Comment: Also, you should attach the images directly on StackOverflow rather than linking the sources.

Comment: Please run through https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/